# Laravel Crons on Elastic Beanstalk Linux AMI 2

Tags: php, cron, elastic-beanstalk, laravel

I am running a Laravel app on Elastic Beanstalk Linux AMI 2.

I am using the following config file in the .ebextensions folder to set up the cron.

```
files:
"/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  * * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/php artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/laralog.log 2>&1

commands:
remove_old_cron:
command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

After deploying, it does not seem at all like the scheduling engine is running on the test instance. I set up a cron to write to my DB every 2 minutes and nothing is happening. Has something changed and now this code will no longer start the Laravel scheduler?

Comment: Have you try to write the command in script and run the script. Sometime `cron` do not "like:/"handle" well `&&` in command

Comment: no, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Put this: `. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/php artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/laralog.log 2>&1` in file (in `root` home directory, Exec `chmod 700 <fillename>` and make record with time to be: `* * * * * root /path/to/your/script`

Comment: but wouldnt that start the scheduler over and over again?

Comment: I do not get it. What I propose do not change the logic.

Comment: ok, can i put that file in the .ebextensions folder?

Comment: just a regular .txt file? .php file?

Comment: It can be any extension, in UNIX/Linux they are not in charge like Windows. But you can add `.sh`

Comment: thanks. either way, it still does not seem to work.